# What is the best way to store custom variables

Tags: variables

I need to store the id and secret key of my FB application. I don't want to write them directly in my template. What do you recommend ?

Comment: I recommend you to store in WordPress options table using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option as this site specific data and not post/category specific.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to store it in WordPress options table using function [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) function as this is site specific data and not post/category specific.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I still feel like it should contain another suggestion so I'll throw in my 2 cents.

I use the wp-config.php file for such cases where you have a global constant that should be accessible everywhere.  This is what WordPress itself does when it needs to store and access such constants as DB_NAME, DB_USER etc.  So my recommendation is to add the following to your wp-config.php like:

```
define('FACEBOOK_ID', VALUE); // Replace VALUE with your actual value
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY', VALUE); // Replace VALUE with your actual value
```

Then in the code you can access these values by simply using the constants **FACEBOOK_ID** and **FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY**

This organizes them all into one safe location and also avoids calls to the DB rather than using an already defined const variable.

EDIT: I forgot to mention if you're working on a php page outside of WordPress, you will have to add something like this to your file: `require_once( __DIR__ . '/wp-config.php');` This example assumes the custom file is in the same directory as wp-config.php